# Changing a program executable filename

Tags: windows

For certain reasons (another program interferes with processes matching ***.exe), I need to rename an executable to foo.exe.  How can I do this while retaining references, shortcuts, file associations, etc?  I don't suppose a computer-wide (including the registry) Find-and-Replace exists?

Comment: Let's avoid the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174452), what's the ACTUAL problem you're trying to deal with?

Comment: The problem is a Java application that monitors process image names and self-terminates if a blacklisted process is run. I've subverted it by renaming the blacklisted executable. I was also able to re-register the file associations within the renamed program (and it points to the renamed program, not the original filename). If you'd like to help with the root of the problem, it's unanswered here: http://superuser.com/questions/692408/disabling-overreaching-java-permissions

Comment: As @techie007 said, we don't encourage questions that exhibit an XY issue. Please clarify your original question if needed.

Answer (score 5):

You don't. This is a very bad idea. No good can come of this. Best course of action is to resolve the root cause instead.

Comment: Especially if there's another EXE someplace named the same thing. :)